# Height of Cylinder inscribed in Sphere

Tags: geometry

```
Find the height of a cylinder of maximum volume inscribed in a sphere of radius R.
```

How do I solve this? I found something online but I don't get why R is the red line in their drawing.

http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Cylinder/OneSol.cyl.html

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This site is devoted to collecting a repository of self-contained questions and answers. It's therefore generally preferable not to pose a substantial portion of a question as a web link, since links tend to break over time. (The [site tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) may be of interest, as well.) As for your question, the red segment joins the center of the sphere to a point of the sphere, so it is a radius. The linked page therefore contains a complete solution to your question.

Comment: $R$ is the radius of the sphere, which provides a constraint on the ratio of the height to the radius of the cylinder

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hey! Thank you for the reply mate, I understand that the website intends to be a repository so that other people can view my question & answers. I would've used an image but since I'm new I can't post images(yet!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

We know that $R$ is a fixed number and we need the height when cylinder has the maximum volume. Therefore, we should eliminate $r$ from the following equation so that we can find the volume in terms of $h$.

---

$$r^2+\frac{h^2}{4}=R^2$$ $$\Downarrow$$ $$r=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{h^2}{4}}$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$V_{cylinder}= \pi r^2 h= \pi (R^2-\frac{h^2}{4})h$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$V_{cylinder}'= \pi R^2- (3/4)\pi h^2 $$

---

Volume function has its maximum value when its derivative is equal to zero.

Namely, when $h= 2R\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The normal height $h$ of the cylinder of the maximum volume inscribed in a sphere of radius $R$ is given as $$h=\frac{2R}{\sqrt{3}}$$ & radius $r$ of the circular section of cylinder $$r=R\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$$ & the maximum volume of cylinder is given as  $$V=\pi r^2 h=\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}\pi R^3 $$